# Azure SQL Server - How do I give a user read only access to the master database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

For a project I'm working with Azure SQL, for usage in a web application I created a user 'justread', which was given select - access on one of the schema's in the database.

I did this in the classical way, in 2 steps:

1. On the master database

   ```
   if exists(select * from sys.database_principals where name = N'justread')
     begin
       drop user [justread]
       drop login [justread]
     end
   go
   if not exists (select * from sys.database_principals where name = N'justread')
     begin 
       create login [justread] with password= N'123456'
     end
   go
   ```
2. On the application database

   ```
   create user [justread] for login [justread] with default_schema=[dbo]
   go
   grant select on schema::dbo to [justread]
   go
   ```

On the application database this works nicely, however, I received a request to allow the same user readonly access to the master database.

Don't ask me why...

I first tried it by assigning the access the same was as I did on the application database:

```
create user [justread] for login [justread] with default_schema=[dbo]
go
grant select on schema::dbo to [justread]
go
```

The first query worked, no problem. But the second failed with the following error:

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Cannot find the schema 'dbo', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I tried googling, found how it is done with a classic SQL Server, but I also got an error message there:

```
grant view server state to [justread]
go

Msg 40520, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

How do I get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, do you want to create tables in master database and grant ‘justread’ user permission on these tables? If that is the case, we are not able to create table in master database in Azure SQL. Master database in Azure SQL is read-only and it is there to hold information about roles, logins and so on.

However, if you want to grant ‘justread’ user permission on system tables of master database in Azure SQL, just execute the following script in master database. I test the process, justread user can access system tables of master database once we execute the script below.

```
create user [justread] for login [justread] with default_schema=[dbo]
 Go
```

Secondly, as per this [official article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186260.aspx), VIEW SERVER STATE is currently not a concept that is supported in Azure SQL, thus you get error message when running the following script.

```
 grant view server state to [justread]
go
```

Answer (score 0):

The user [justread] was created with intent to execute simple dataqueries on my application's database. For reasons unknown to me the client also needs this user to have read-only access to the "Master" database.

Using the following query I managed to give [justread] the required access, so I can execute queries on the master database.

```html
create user [justread] for login [justread] with default_schema=[dbo]
Go
```

Some tables still appear to be out of reach though as the following error message seems to indicate:

[image]

For the moment, this might suffice however.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've granted readonly permission to external users (in the Azure AD) to my database:

```
CREATE USER [externaluser] FROM  EXTERNAL PROVIDER  WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [externaluser]
GO
```

Related articles:

- [Controlling and granting database access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins)
- [Database-Level Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles)